# Download all contents of HTML file powershell

Tags: html, powershell

How do you download all of the content from a HTML file? For example I save a webpage in Chrome it is different to what I get when I run the given code. I want to get the same results as anybody else would, when saving the webpage from a browser.

I attempted multiple scripts from the internet and had had no luck.

```
$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile('http://localhost','C:\Users\admin\Downloads\test.html')
```

Comment: i used to use http://www.httrack.com for that purpose. with powershell you had to parse the html for any links and download those also.

Comment: Did you get an error message from this code?

Comment: no errors from the code, it just didnt output the whole html file

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://localhost' -OutFile 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\test.html'
```

Comment: that does not get all of the html code, if you save from chrome directly its twice as big

Comment: @Aaron If it's only the size that differs, maybe it's down to encoding? Check if some characters won't display correctly.

Comment: Its a different size because the file has more data in it. Its missing lots of the code.

Comment: @Aaron Is it cut off at a certain point or are there bits in between missing?

Comment: It worked for me as I downloaded an XML file.